# Align data as an array for tournament bracket php json

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a bracket data and and it accepts data in the follwing form given blow

```
[// Round 1 bracket
    [// row 1
        {
            "name" : 'test name',
            'id'   : 1
        }, {
            "name" : 'test last',
            'id'   : 2
        }
    ], [ row 2
        {
            "name" : 'test name',
            'id'   : 1
        }, {
            "name" : 'test last',
            'id'   : 2
        }
    ]
], [// Round 2 Bracket
    [ //row 1
        {
            "name" : 'test name',
            'id'   : 1
        }, {
            "name" : 'test last',
            'id'   : 2
        }
    ]
]
```

but the main problem is that on json I have to create multi dimentional array and the data is getting from mysqli which is 1 table

```
| player_id  | player_name | participant_id | participant_name | round |
| ---------- | ----------- | -------------- | ---------------- | ----- |
| 1          | Mark Alan   | 3              | Steve            | 1     |
| 2          | John Doe    | 4              | Sean Henshaw     | 1     |
| 1          | Mark Alan   | 2              | John Doe         | 2     |
```

so how do I achieve this how do i make in this format with foreach loop I am unable to set data with this format here is the sample php code i created with this it is possible to output json data but while looping thourgh database query how do I arrange data in array form to set for brackets

```
$data = array(
array(
    array(
        'player_id'  => 1,
        'player_name'   => 'Mark Alan',
        'round' => 1
    ), array(
        'participant_id'   => 3,
        'participant_name'   => 'Steve',
        'round' => 1
    )
), array(
    array(
        'player_id'  => 2,
        'player_name'   => 'John Doe',
        'round' => 1
    ), array(
        'participant_id'   => 4,
        'participant_name'   => 'Sean Henshaw',
        'round' => 1
    )
) 
), array(
    array(
        array(
            'player_id'  => 1,
            'player_name'   => 'Mark Alan',
            'round' => 2
        ), array(
            'participant_id'   => 2,
            'participant_name'   => 'John Doe',
            'round' => 2
        )
    )
);
```

so Above is the output which i placed by my self nwo with running a single loop capturing data from the databse within single loop how can i make above formatted data I used the given code below but when it is next round a new array should be created then round 3 and so on

```
$bracket = array();
foreach($data as $key => $dt) {
    $bracket[] = array(
        array(
            'name' => $dt['player_name'],
                'id' => $dt['player_id'],
        ),array(
            
            'name' => $dt['participant_id'],
                'id' => $dt['participant_name'],
        )
    );
}
```

This above code prints me correct data but i am not been able to seperate the rounds

```
[
    [
        {"name":"Mark Alan","id":1},
        {"name":3,"id":"Steve"}
    ], 
    [
        {"name":"John Doe","id":2},
        {"name":4,"id":"Sean Henshaw"}
    ],  
    [
        {"name":"Mark Alan","id":1},
        {"name":2,"id":"John Doe"}
    ]
]
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong? Wouldn't `json_encode($data)` give required results?

Comment: yes json_encode will give results how to I define array in the above format which I am looking to achieve I am calling data from the database mysqli_fetch_assoc will run single loop

Comment: @Justinas I edited my above question to give you more breif please check I hope now I most probably cleared you

Comment: Probably `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` on `json_encode`? You have different constants you may use to modfiy the output of `json_encode`. Have a look into the docs: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php

Comment: so if I just run the loop will this create me array within array no i don't think so outputting data is the end thing first of all I am trying to achieve is to making the format of an array as in the first you can see it only accepts data in the above given format so I have to set accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should map your database results to new array:

```php
$data = [];

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
   $data[$row['round']] ??= [];

   $data[$row['round']][] = [
        [
            'name' => $row['player_name'],
            'id' => $row['player_id'],
        ],
        [
            'name' => $row['participant_name'],
            'id' => $row['participant_id'],
        ],
   ];
}

$dataJson = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in E:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 69 line number 69 i this 'id' => $row['player_id'],
       69 ],
        [
            'name' => $row['participant_name'],

Comment: @UsmanKhan There is no such code in my example *AND* it was written without actually running it, just in SO editor, so there can be errors, fix them on your own

Comment: I fixed it by my self and end result is not what I wanted in my code end array you can see by using your code I am close to what I wanted but the separation for array for round is not being achieved I am damn close you can see my code

Comment: @UsmanKhan I see your code: 1. there is no separation of rounds (`$data[$row['round']]` part is missing). 2. You mixed ID and Name fields in place

Comment: after using your code and making implementation and changes to it i suceded